# C# . Generar reporte

Tags: c#

Alguien me podria ayudar, necesito saber cual opción es la mejor para generar un reporte en c# con base de datos access

Necesito generar un reporte de los empleados con su asistencia.

Ejemplo:

```
                            Empleado: 0001 hasta 0002

                        Fecha:  16/12/2019 a  17/12/2019
```

---

0001  JUAN CARLOS LOPEZ <-- (Datos de tabla empleados)

```
     16/12/2019 <----- ASISTENCIA  <-- (Datos de tabla asistencia)

     17/12/2019 <----- ASISTENCIA  <-- (Datos de tabla asistencia)
```

0002 FERNANDO LOPEZ RDG <-- (Datos de tabla empleados)

```
     16/12/2019 <----- ASISTENCIA <-- (Datos de tabla asistencia)

     17/12/2019 <----- ASISTENCIA <-- (Datos de tabla asistencia)
```

---

Quiero generar algo como ese ejemplo. Son dos tablas, la de empleados y la de asistencia, estan ligados por el ID del empleado, espero darme a entender.

No se si eso se pueda hacer en report viewer o crystal report. Trato de agrupar por empleados y el sub grupo seria su asitencia dentro de un rango de fechas y de empleados. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Con ambos se puede hacer `Report Viewer` o `Crystal Report` , qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: La verdad estoy muy perdido. Genere una consulta con inner join de las dos tablas y muestro el resultado en un datagrdiview pero no me da el formato que necesito.

Comment: Tendras alguna idea de donde buscar informacion para generar reportes con parametros, ya que utilizo varios parametros para la consulta.

Comment: Y lo importante, como brinca o insertar una linea en blanco para cuando es otro empleado

Comment: Si buscas algo sencillo puede ser primero un texto y es decir te concentras en extraer la informacion y pasarla a un documento, despues puedes usar un excel o pdf. Pero depende de que haras despues con el reporte.

Comment: El reporte se debe imprimir, pero en realidad no importa si es de un .txt o de un pdf, solo busco el acomodo de esa manera.Espero darme a entender, quiero ejecutar la consulta con el beetwen y me de ese diseño

Comment: Hay mucha información al respecto, [mira aquí](https://es.lmgtfy.com/?q=generar+reporte+con+crystal+report+c%23&pp=1) , Creo que primero debes intentar hacerlo, viendo ejemplos en códigos o vídeos y luego si tienes errores, vienes y preguntas y es mas fácil ayudarte con un problema en concreto. [Todo en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=generar+reporte+con+crystal+report+c%23)

Comment: Okay muchas gracias. Voy a intentar. en verdad gracias

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, Espero aun me puedan ayudar. Ya realize el reporte en report viewer, es una consulta con un inner join donde uno las dos tablas y con una matriz muestro los datos. Ahora me podrian orientar para obtener el formato que necesito? Porfavor. Se lo agradeceria mucho. No se por que atributo agruparlos